# Deleting space at the beginning of every paragraph in Word Document

Tags: ms-word

A Word document has many paragraphs with an initial space. How do I delete this extra space using Word VBA. The code should loop through all the paras in the document and delete the extra space (if any)  at the beginning of the para.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used the following code to resolve the problem. The extra space at the beginning of the para was not really a space character but chr(160) which looked like a space. Hence, the chr(160) in the code below.

```
Sub Findfirstcharacterinpara()
Dim wdoc As Document
Dim para As Paragraph
Set wdoc = ActiveDocument
For Each para In wdoc.Paragraphs
If para.Range.Characters(1) = Chr(160) Then para.Range.Characters(1).Delete
Next para
End Sub
```